# Conditional rewriting, how to manage PHP scripts?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I need to create an *API gateway* that I can't test... But the problem is about manage PHP scripts.

### What I need

- all files HTML or PHP
- special names as `my1` and `issn` redirect to localhost at port 2018
- special names as `my2` and `my3` redirect to `ETC.php`

### Explanation

[Pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode) with details of "What I need",

```
if ($uri exists) {
    if extension is .php use it with php7.0-fpm.sock
    else use it as static page;
} else 
   try the @proxy_rewrite_engine;

@proxy_rewrite_engine =  
  if (regex ^\(my[23])$ use 
       ETC.php;
  elseif (regex ^/(\d+)/my1$  use 
       http://127.0.0.1:2018?type=int&val=$1
  elseif ^/([0-9]+\-\d+[Xx]?)/issn$  use 
       http://127.0.0.1:2018?type=str&val=$1
  else 
       say error;
```

### What I try

My problematic solution, please show a real solution, translating the "Explanation" section into concrete and correct NGINX script code.

... Below, my wrong-NGINX-script for clues and inspiration, it is not the solution... Need to use `if` instead neasted `location`?  The `fastcgi_param` is valid? Can I group locations?

```
  server {
    server_name  test.mytest.news;

    root   /var/www/test;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    location  / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
    }

    location  ~ \.php$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
      include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf; # without SCRIPT_FILENAME 
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location  @proxy {
      rewrite ^\?(my[23])$                 $document_root/ETC.php?cmd=$1 
             last;
      rewrite  ^/(\d+)/my1$                ?type=int&val=$1 
             break;
      rewrite  ^/([0-9]+\-\d+[Xx]?)/issn$  ?type=str&val=$1  
             break;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2018;
    }

    include  snippets/ssl-test.mytest.news.conf;

  } #end server
```

---

NOTE for @cnst comment: Suppose that what I need when say
 *"all files HTML or PHP"*   **=**   the `try_files`  must to try other files tham index.htm, can be folders, imagens and other files.

Comment: this is not related to PHP

Comment: Thanks @hassan. I will edit tags and some text

Comment: About user of down-vote, please **explain it here**.

Comment: so, which parts work, and which don't?

Comment: @cnst the `my1` and some others not working... But the main problem is that I can't test all, I need a **script 100% reliable**, by its construction  (not by testing).

Comment: @cnst and others, see [this similar problem as *concrete example*](https://serverfault.com/q/862772).

Comment: @PeterKrauss can the regex match for any files that exist?  E.g., do the files that exist have any sort of a unique prefix/suffix?

Comment: Hi @cnst... I will use this solution in two contexts, in one I can constraint files to index.htm and some root links, in other is generic and can be folders, PHP, etc. So, if there are a big difference or opportunity to optimizations, you can use one or other context to highlight the advantages of your solution.

Comment: I think you might want to re-word the question, then — whether or not the constraints are present makes the solutions entirely different.

Comment: Thanks @cnst, I edited with an note, about what "all files HTML" is... and supposing that is never an empty set, have more than 2 or 3 files, and the filenames are not planed.

Comment: IMHO, you wouldn't get a "script 100% reliable, by its construction" if you simply throw a bunch of independent problem statements as a start (especially as they don't allow much flexibility of what exact behaviours must be implemented).

Comment: @cnst, I think that understand what you say... But, how to express "problem statements" to obtain good solutions? Do you have a link or links with good examples? In this context of Nginx config-script needs (API Gateways).

Comment: @cnst, please post any of your suggestions as an answer, I will appreciate (!)   and adpt it for my needs, no problem.

Comment: @PeterKrauss, as per your suggestion, I've posted my suggestions as an answer.  I hope you find it valuable, although I do realise that it may not be the answer you were looking for — I can only read software's mind, not that of people. ;-)  If it does a good job of answering the question, don't forget to click award and/or accept (otherwise, at least half of the value of the bounty will be lost).

Answer (score 3):

If the desire is to have "*a script 100% reliable, by its construction (not by testing)*", then putting multiple independent issues in a single question is probably not the best approach.

1. Your rationale behind having to check existence of files prior to passing the request to a separate backend is not entirely clear, especially if the request is matching a given regular expression, like `issn$`.  Best approach would be to use separate `location` directives for each distinct handling of the case.
2. More specifically, the following is also wrong with your approach: the regular expression in `rewrite ^\?(my[23])$` is unlikely to match any request, as all external requests start with a slash.
3. Likewise, as per https://serverfault.com/a/864778/110020, the replacement string in `rewrite  ^/(\d+)/my1$                ?type=int&val=$1` is unlikely to be correct; in fact, when I've tried your code as above, the following is the `500 Internal Server Error` I've gotten, as per `nginx/error.log`:

   `2017/07/24 08:46:22 [error] 45776#0: *2 the rewritten URI has a zero length, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /44444/my1 HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:`

   This happens because you indeed rewrite URI to become an empty one — the question mark, `?`, and anything after it, is generally not part of URI in request processing within nginx, so, as such, the URI is indeed entirely empty.  Solution: at least put a slash in front of `?` (i.e., `/?id=`), or, better yet, a full name of the script that must be activated (especially since this is merely an internal redirect).

Answer (score 0):

Nginx works good with large configs. Bad idea optimize nginx.conf.
Do it simple, it'll work hard:)
I think config like this will work fine:

```
# Try to load existing files
location  / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewriteIt;
}

# Handle all requests except two other locations below
location  @rewriteIt {
   # Send it to index.php
   rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?cmd=$1 last;
}

# This RegExp location will rewrite to ETC.php
# It is more priority, than "/" and @rewriteIt
location ~ ^(my2|my3) $ {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /ETC.php?cmd=$1 last;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf; # without SCRIPT_FILENAME 
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

# This RegExp location will proxy to 2018 port
# It is more priority, than "/" and @rewriteIt
location ~ ^(my1|issn) $ {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2018;
}

# This location handles all php files to php-fpm
location  ~ \.php$ {
  try_files $uri =404;
  include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf; # without SCRIPT_FILENAME 
  fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
```

Comment: Hi Andrewus, your script make sense, and is a solution (!)... There are a way to translate it into a "less verbose" version? I was looking for, also, to a way to group all fastcgi-PHP directives, and avoid regex duplication in `location ~ regex ... rewrite regex`

Comment: Hi Andrews, see my comments and the othe answer to **adapt your answer and get the bounty!** You're the only one who's complying with the bounty-request,  "show a complete NGINX script".

Comment: Sorry for no answers for a long time.

Comment: Changed conf with ETC.php to `rewrite ^(.*)$ /ETC.php?cmd=$1 last;` -- this syntax works:) And no regex duplication.